# i need to bind the context menu with the tag , but this code didnt work for me

Tags: wpf, xaml

i need to bind the context menu with the tag , but this code didnt work for me.

```
    <TextBox Width="100" Name="dd" Tag="jatin" Height="50" Text="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

        <TextBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="harsh"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="jatin"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Grid},FallbackValue=BindingFailed}"></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBox.ContextMenu>

    </TextBox>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
```